# sql primary key "mapping table ?"

Tags: sql

i have a database for university so the students take many courses but each student have id as primary key also each course have an id as primary key its not allowed to have duplicate id at same table what should i use to make a table that same id but different courses id

Comment: What are you looking to ***do***?

Comment: i want to make a student table have multiple values of courses how ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normalized relational database,  when you have a situation where items from one table can be associated with many items in a second table, and likewise those related items can be associated with many items in the first table, you should use a third table to store those relationships.  In your case,  that table might be called Enrollments.

You can use JOIN operations on that third table to relate, group, and aggregate across that relationship. You can also store any metadata associated with that relationship in the JOIN- table, for example you might store the enrollment date there.

Answer (score 0):

Like vicatcu said, create a third table

Course_id | Student_id

The ID's of the courses and the students are uniq in their own tables. The relation between course < - > student is stored in that third table.